# Android Espresso black-box testing

Tags: android, android-testing, android-espresso

Does anyone try to do `black-box testing` with `Android Espresso`?

Could anyone provides me with some simple example?

I had tried some example before, but failed every time!

Example, I had tried this one:

```
public class ApplicationTest extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2
{

private static final String ACTIVITY_CLASSNAME = "com.example.kai_yu.blackboxtest";

private static Class launchActivityClass;
static
{
    try
    {
        launchActivityClass = Class.forName(ACTIVITY_CLASSNAME);
    }
    catch (ClassNotFoundException e)
    {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}

public ApplicationTest()
{
    super(launchActivityClass);
}

@Test
public void testClick()
{

}
```

}

But Android Studio said:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.kai_yu.blackboxtest"

com.example.kai_yu.blackboxtest is applicationId which is another installed application on my phone
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Espresso can only run as part of an instrumentation test. 
Instrumentation tests can only act upon the app under test ( i.e. the target of the instrumentation ).

UIAutomator might be better for your use case.

https://developer.android.com/tools/testing-support-library/index.html#UIAutomator

Answer (score 0):

In `Espresso` docs you would find this line:

```
 While it can be used for black-box testing, Espresso's full power is unlocked by those who are familiar with the code base under test."
```

For that reason Espresso testing is called by `gray-box testing`.

If you're not familiar with programming in Java or Android, or you want just to write `black-box testing` in the clearest way as possible try to learn instead of `Espresso` this framework

> `Calabash-iOS` and `Calabash-Android` are the underlying low-level libraries that empower the Cucumber tool to run automated functional tests on Android...

Website: https://calaba.sh/

GitHub: https://github.com/calabash

Here would you find how and why to start using this framework:
http://blog.teddyhyde.com/2013/11/04/a-better-way-to-test-android-applications-using-calabash/

Comment: Calabash is depricated now. Question was about possibility of testing without source code and not understanding it.

Answer (score 0):

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
@LargeTest
public class EspressoTest1 extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<MainActivity>{

        public EspressoTest1() {
            super(MainActivity.class);
        }

        @Before 
         public void setUp() throws Exception {
            super.setUp();
            injectInstrumentation(InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation());
        }

        @Test 
        public void test1ChatId() {
            getActivity();
            onView(withId(R.id.anuja)).check(matches(isDisplayed()));
        }

        @After        public void tearDown() throws Exception {
            super.tearDown();
        }
}
```

There are two ways to write Espresso Test case one is as per shown above
The Examples are taken from this blog
http://qaautomated.blogspot.in/p/blog-page.html

Where you can find details of hot to run the espresso test case in detail.